# Cakephp 2.7 creating a pagination on a comments in a certain Topic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Hi I am stuck in building the pagination of my comment in a certain topic. At first I use ajax with custom appending of html tags but I find out later I cannot echo or print the cake Form helpers on the view. Anyone here can give some idea of how to do it?

This is my Controller code

```
public function view($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
    }

    $topic = $this->Topic->viewTopicAndComments($id);

    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($topic);
    // exit;

    if (empty($topic))
    {
        $topic[0] = $this->Topic->viewById($id);
    }

    if (!$topic) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
    }

    $this->set('topic', $topic);
}
```

While in my Model

```
public function viewTopicAndComments($id)
{
    return $this->Comment->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Topic.id' => $id,
                'Topic.deleted_flag' => ACTIVE_FLAG,
                'Comment.deleted_flag' => ACTIVE_FLAG,
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Topic.id',
                'Topic.title',
                'Topic.content',
                'Topic.created',
                'User.id',
                'User.firstname',
                'User.lastname',
                'User.middlename',
                'Comment.content',
                'Comment.user_id',
                'Comment.id',
                'Comment.created',
            ),
            'limit' => 5,
            'order' => array('Comment.created DESC'),
            )
    );
}
```

And in my custom js for ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.right_col').scroll(function(){

        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
            innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight(),
            documentElement = $(this)[0].scrollHeight,
            rowCount = $('#rowCount').val(),
            topic = $('#topic_id').val();

            if (scrollTop + innerHeight >= documentElement)
            {
                // var counter = 0,
                //  comment_id = 0;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '/comments/fetch_comments/'+ rowCount +'/'+ topic,
                    cache: 'false',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    beforeSend: function()
                    {
                        $('.loader-container').css('display','block');
                    },
                    success: function(response)
                    {

                        $('.loader-container').css('display','none');

                        if (response[0] !== undefined)
                        {

                            for (var i in response)
                            {
                                console.log(response[i]['Comment']);

                                console.log(response);
                                var newVal = parseInt(rowCount) + 5;

                                var html = "<div class='row'>"+
                                                "<div class='col-md-12'>"+
                                                    "<div class='x_panel'>"+
                                                        "<div class='comment_wrapper'>"+
                                                            "<div class='comment_profile_pic'>"+
                                                                "<img src='/custom/images/user.png' alt='avatar'/>"+
                                                            "</div>"+
                                                            "<div class='content'>"+
                                                                "<a><b>"+ escapeHtml(response[i]['User'].lastname.capitalize()) +', '+ escapeHtml(response[i]['User'].firstname.capitalize()) +' '+ escapeHtml(response[i]['User'].middlename.capitalize()) +"</b></a>"+
                                                                "<a class='timestamp'> "+ response[i]['Comment'].created +"</a>"+
                                                            "</div>"+
                                                        "</div>"+
                                                    "</div>"+
                                                "</div>"+
                                            "</div>";


                                $('#rowCount').val(newVal);
                                $('#comment-block').append(html);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

    });

    String.prototype.capitalize = function()
    {
        return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
    }
    function escapeHtml(text) {

        var map = {
            '&': '&amp;',
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '"': '&quot;',
            "'": '&#039;'
        };

        return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
    }

});
```

Comment: Please post you code to make helping you easier.

Comment: @maxhb try to look it back